# Align two elements to the top and bottom of a table cell

Tags: html, html-table, vertical-alignment

I have a table with multiple rows and columns and each cell contains a link and a few small images.  The link needs to be aligned to the top of the cell and the images need to be aligned to the bottom.  Unfortunately using the vertical-align attribute doesn't work and both elements are being placed in the middle of the cell.  Here is the HTML I have so far:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='width:120px; height:90px;'>
      <a href='1.html' style='vertical-align:top'>Link 1</a>
      <div style='vertical-align:bottom'><img src='1-1.jpg' /><img src='1-2.jpg' /></div>
    </td>
    <td style='width:120px; height:90px;'>
      <a href='2.html' style='vertical-align:top'>Link 2</a>
      <div style='vertical-align:bottom'><img src='2-1.jpg' /><img src='2-2.jpg' /></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> ... </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: td height and width is also defined at 120 x 90 px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Updated

Referred to http://davidwalsh.name/table-cell-position-absolute and came up with the following answer...

```css
.tlink {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.bimg {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table height="250" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="tlink">
        <a href='#'>Link One</a>
        <div class="bimg">
          <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3575/3293166516_de2cd751fc.jpg" width="50" height="50" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this solution using the style element like you did, and tried it inline using the style attribute, but I am seeing no change in vertical alignment.

Comment: That works!  Now I understand why divs are often preferred over tables.

Comment: -1 The first part of your answer seems to be wrong. The second part (the fiddle) is doing something else (alternately aligning cells top and bottom) that you could just as easily do with `<table>`s. It would be helpful if you would remove the first part of the answer and clarify the second.

Comment: Really bad answer. 90% of this answer consists of repeating exactly what the question said did NOT work. And unsurprisingly, it didn't work. Which also indicates that the answerer didn't even test the answer before posting it.  Then the second part (not even included on this actual page) shows very poor practise of using the wrong tool for a job (if you want to display a table, use the table tag.)

Comment: Sincere apologies for posting a wrong answer. I went through the original answer and I can clearly see the flaws. I've updated the answer. Surely there will be areas to improve in the updated answer as well and suggestions for the same are welcome.